# How can I update a User profile node (web)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created users with Firebase email authentication, and I stored the user profile data in Firebase database in a users node and the childs are the UID.

Something like this

```
users:
      UID: 
          DisplayName: "A name"
          DisplayPic:"Firebase DownloadURL"
          DisplayTerms:"on"
          DsiplayEmail:"enail@mail.com"
```

So I want to give the users the option of change their profile picture by uploading a picture to Firebase storage and updating the DownloadURL value in the DisplayPic node.

Im trying something like this:

```
 /*************uploadImage************/
//get variables
var filebutton = document.getElementById('filebutton');

//listen for file selction
filebutton.addEventListener('change', function(e){
   //get the file
   var file = e.target.files[0];



    var metadata = {
        'contentType': file.type
      };

   var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('userProfilePic/' + file.name).put(file, metadata).then(function(snapshot){
//savr image url to db
   var url = snapshot.metadata.downloadURLs[0];
// Get a key for a new onject.
   var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  firebase.database().ref().child(user.uid).child('DisplayPic').push( {
      DisplayPic:userpic=url,
  });
```

But I'm getting a permission denied Error.

And here's my rules:

```
 "users": {
      "$uid": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        // grants read access to any user who is logged in with an email and password
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }

    }
```

The picture uploads correctly but the DisplayPic node is not updated. Any ideas?